# Use pipe to send command into python interpreter

Tags: python, c, pipe

I would like to create an application on windows (in any languages, there is no restrictions) where you could write some commands, send them into a python interpreter and get the result. Therefore, I immediately think of using pipes. But I have a problem, I know how to get file descriptor of subprocess, but not of an application like python.

Is there a way of getting the file descriptor of a subprocess like python interpreter?

Comment: what commands? Python code or own commands? Python script can get data from pipe using `input()` or better `sys.stdin.read()` and then you can run use it to run some code and send it to pipe using `print()` or `sys.stdout.write()`.

Comment: to send code to interpreter you can use interactive mode `python -i` - ie. `echo '1+2' | python -i` but it will display `>>>` and other elements which it display normally in interactive mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-` as argument for `python` it will read code from `stdin` so it can read from `pipe` too

```
echo 'print(1+2)' | python -

echo 'import os;print(os.listdir("."))' | python -
```

But it will run every string in new interpreter so it will not remember previous values.

---

BTW: But maybe you want to build something similar to Python Shell (interctive mode) with own commands. Then you could use standard module [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) or external module [Python Prompt Toolkit](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

It creates program which displays prompt, you write own command and it executes it and display prompt again.